# ios tabbar icons not showing right- adding non flat icons to ios7 tabbar and toolbar

Tags: ios, toolbar, tabbar

I want to show some icon like below icon in my uitabbar and uitoolbar:

[image]

but when I am showing this icon to my application it looks like below:

[image]

I think it is because ios render the icons of tab-bar and toolbar.

Is there a way so that we can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the image on the UITabBarItem, pass it in as:

```
UIImage *tabBarItemImage = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

This tells iOS 7 not to treat the image as a template image.

See [UIImage class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode%3a) for more info.

Comment: I add the image in story board. Is there any options there?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure as I don't use storyboards

Comment: Because in iOS 7, Apple introduced the ability for UIImage's to be used as "template" images and let the tintColor of their UIImageView colour them. If you want to opt out of this functionality then you must specify that your image should be used as the original image (UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal)

Comment: but I have this problem in both ios6 and ios 7. The UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal fixed my problem in ios 7 but still there is problem in ios 6

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't think you can stop this in iOS 6 because the UITabBar wasn't very customisable back then. I could be incorrect though.